# How to get current location latitude longitude in iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, core-location

i want to get my current location lat long for this i have written some code but i getting wrong place's lat long 
here is my code.

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; 
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
float latitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
float longitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;
```

Comment: Testing on simulator? Check simulator location

Comment: You can't get the location right away after you initialise the CLLocationManager. It is an async process and may take some time. Nevertheless, you can use its delegation protocol (as suggested by someone already).

Comment: how to check simulator location?

Comment: in the simulator menu Debug -> Location to change the location

Answer (score 2):

To get the current location, write this code:

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate=self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.distanceFilter=kCLDistanceFilterNone;

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Then implement the delegate methods:

```
// CLLocationManagerDelegate

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
   didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
   fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    // Handle location updates
} 

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // Handle error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the delegate correctly: `[locationManager setDelegate:self]`
2. Implement the correct delegate method [`locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007124-CH3-SW16)
3. Read out the locations array. The last item in the array is the most recent found location.